# What is the proper way to send a json body with axios from React to Django Rest Api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I am trying to send a post request to my django rest API using Axios from a react frontend.

**Home.js**

Here I am getting the value from the form and setting up the state and sending the value to the function that will call the API on submit

```
const [query, setQuery] = useState({
    search: "",
  })
 const { search } = query;

// function handle submit  
const onSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(search);
    navigate(`/search/${search}`);
    fetchSearch(search); //fucntion that deals with the api call
  };
```

**searchApi.js**
this function deals with api call

```
export const fetchSearch = async (search) => {
  console.log("the data being recieved ", search);

  const config = {
    header: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
  };

  const body = JSON.stringify({ search }); // 1
  const body = {            // 2
    
    search: search,
  };

  console.log("this is the body", body);

  try {
    let response = await axios.post(`${url}/get-teacher/`, body, config);
    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

Now let me tell you the problem I am facing, as shown above, I have comments beside the **body**. If I send the **body //1** as a request, then django throws this error and I get an internal server error

```
AssertionError: Expected a `Response`, `HttpResponse` or `HttpStreamingResponse` to be returned from the view, but received a `<class 'NoneType'>`
```

And if I send the **body //2** as a request then it works perfectly.

**the view that handles the request**

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def search(request):

    query = request.data.get('search')
    
    
    print("this is the query recieved" ,query)
        
    if query is not None:
    
        try:
        
            user = TeacherDetail.objects.filter(is_verified= True)
            
            # to chain lookups to query multiple fields at once
            lookups = Q(name__icontains = query) | Q(location__icontains = query) | Q(full_address__icontains = query) | Q(name_of_school__icontains = query) | Q(experience__icontains = query) | Q(teach_for_no_days__icontains = query) | Q(subject__icontains = query) | Q(shift__icontains = query) | Q(teach_class__icontains = query) | Q(board__icontains = query)
            
            user = user.filter(lookups)
            
            serializer = TeacherDetailSerializer(user, many = True)
            
            return Response(serializer.data)
        
        except Exception as e:
            e = str(e)

            return Response({'status':status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND, "message": e})
    else:
        
        response = {
            "message": "Query is empty",
            "status": status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
        }
```

I want to know why this is happening because when I console.log() the **body //1** is see

```
{"search":"swastika"}
```

which is exactly what we send to the body of the request.

Please correct me where I am wrong and tell me the proper way to send the body as JSON